# Webpack 3.0: How can I exclude node_modules from build?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-3

I tried to add 'target:node' to the webpack.dev.js to exclude node_modules from my bundle file. This results in an error. Now I have 'target:web' but has the node_modules back in. This is my config file for the applicationpart(trying to use DllReferencePlugin):

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  target:'web',

  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  cache: true,
  devtool: "eval", //or cheap-module-eval-source-map
  entry: {
    app: path.join(__dirname, "client/app", "app.js")
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "buildf"),
    filename: "ha.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].js"
  },
  plugins: [
    //Typically you'd have plenty of other plugins here as well
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: path.join(__dirname, "client"),
      manifest: require("./build/vendor-manifest.json")
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, "client") //important for performance!
        ],
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
        ],
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true, //important for performance
          plugins: ["transform-regenerator"],
          presets: ["es2015", "stage-0"]
        }
      },

      { test: /\.(scss|sass)$/, loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'css-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

How can I exclude the node_modules folder from the ha.js (app bundle) build? for the complete code see [here](https://github.com/dimitri-a/NG6-starter)

Comment: What do you mean 'exclude'? Put it to separate js file?

Answer (score 1):

**[Here](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) an example:**

```
 rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,  // <---
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```